# Issue downloading an image file using RestTemplate

Tags: java

I am trying to download an image file ( I have tried with .jpg and .png) using a REST get call. When I upload the file using restTemplate the Content-Type in the header response says "content-type:application/json; charset=UTF-8". When I try to use restTemplate to download the same file I am getting the exception below. When I copy the URL that restTemplate is using into the browser, it properly downloads the file but shows "Content-Type: image/jpeg; charset=binary". Here is the code I'm using to try download.

```
try{

    // Prepare acceptable media type
    List<MediaType> acceptableMediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
    acceptableMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Content-Type", "image/jpeg; charset=binary");


    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);

    // Send the request as GET
    ResponseEntity<String> result= restTemplate.exchange(downloadURL, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);

    String body = result.getBody();
    System.out.println("DownloadFile: "+ result.getBody());
}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}



java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: binary
    at java.nio.charset.Charset.forName(Charset.java:543)
    at org.springframework.http.MediaType.checkParameters(MediaType.java:299)
       at org.springframework.http.MediaType.<init>(MediaType.java:263)
       at org.springframework.http.MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.java:584)
       at org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.getContentType(HttpHeaders.java:286)
       at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:64)
       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:619)
       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:1)
       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:446)
       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:401)
       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:377)
```

Comment: I think instead of charset = binary replce with this charset utf-8

Comment: I did try that and I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You going to need to use to need to use a custom converter for restTemplate.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.springframework.http.HttpInputMessage;
import org.springframework.http.HttpOutputMessage;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;

public class BufferedImageHttpMessageConverter implements HttpMessageConverter<BufferedImage> {

    public List<MediaType> getSupportedMediaTypes() {
        return Collections.singletonList(new MediaType("image", "jpeg"));
    }

    public boolean supports(Class<? extends BufferedImage> clazz) {
        return BufferedImage.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    public BufferedImage read(Class<BufferedImage> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws IOException {
        return ImageIO.read(inputMessage.getBody());
    }

    public void write(BufferedImage image, HttpOutputMessage message) throws IOException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented");
    }

}
```

To add the converter in the XML way

```
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="BufferedImageHttpMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And then the call

```
    restTemplate.getForObject(downloadURL, BufferedImage.class, variables);
```

This was taken from https://spring.io/blog/2009/03/27/rest-in-spring-3-resttemplate

Answer (score 0):

Now Spring already have such converter so you don't need to create one, just add it in configuration

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    restTemplate.setMessageConverters(
            Arrays.asList(new BufferedImageHttpMessageConverter()));
    return restTemplate;
}
```